# IPv6 raw socket programming with native C

Tags: c, sockets, networking, network-programming, ipv6

I am working on IPv6 and need to craft an IPv6 packet from scratch and put it into a buffer. Unfortunately I do not have much experience with C. From a tutorial I have successfully done the same thing with IPv4 by defining

```
struct ipheader {
 unsigned char      iph_ihl:5, /* Little-endian */
                iph_ver:4;
 unsigned char      iph_tos;
 unsigned short int iph_len;
 unsigned short int iph_ident;
 unsigned char      iph_flags;
 unsigned short int iph_offset;
 unsigned char      iph_ttl;
 unsigned char      iph_protocol;
 unsigned short int iph_chksum;
 unsigned int       iph_sourceip;
 unsigned int       iph_destip;
};

/* Structure of a TCP header */
struct tcpheader {
 unsigned short int tcph_srcport;
 unsigned short int tcph_destport;
 unsigned int       tcph_seqnum;
 unsigned int       tcph_acknum;
 unsigned char      tcph_reserved:4, tcph_offset:4;
 // unsigned char tcph_flags;
  unsigned int
       tcp_res1:4,       /*little-endian*/
       tcph_hlen:4,      /*length of tcp header in 32-bit words*/
       tcph_fin:1,       /*Finish flag "fin"*/
       tcph_syn:1,       /*Synchronize sequence numbers to start a connection*/
       tcph_rst:1,       /*Reset flag */
       tcph_psh:1,       /*Push, sends data to the application*/
       tcph_ack:1,       /*acknowledge*/
       tcph_urg:1,       /*urgent pointer*/
       tcph_res2:2;
 unsigned short int tcph_win;
 unsigned short int tcph_chksum;
 unsigned short int tcph_urgptr;
};
```

and fill the packet content in like this:

```
// IP structure
   ip->iph_ihl = 5;
   ip->iph_ver = 6;
   ip->iph_tos = 16;
   ip->iph_len = sizeof (struct ipheader) + sizeof (struct tcpheader);
   ip->iph_ident = htons(54321);
   ip->iph_offset = 0;
   ip->iph_ttl = 64;
   ip->iph_protocol = 6; // TCP
   ip->iph_chksum = 0; // Done by kernel

   // Source IP, modify as needed, spoofed, we accept through command line argument
   ip->iph_sourceip = inet_addr("1922.168.1.128");
   // Destination IP, modify as needed, but here we accept through command line argument
   ip->iph_destip = inet_addr(1922.168.1.1);

   // The TCP structure. The source port, spoofed, we accept through the command line
   tcp->tcph_srcport = htons(atoi("1024"));
   // The destination port, we accept through command line
   tcp->tcph_destport = htons(atoi("4201"));
   tcp->tcph_seqnum = htons(1);
   tcp->tcph_acknum = 0;
   tcp->tcph_offset = 5;
   tcp->tcph_syn = 1;
   tcp->tcph_ack = 0;
   tcp->tcph_win = htons(32767);
   tcp->tcph_chksum = 0; // Done by kernel
   tcp->tcph_urgptr = 0;
   // IP checksum calculation
   ip->iph_chksum = csum((unsigned short *) buffer, (sizeof (struct ipheader) + sizeof (struct tcpheader)));
```

However for IPv6 I have not find a similar way. What I already found is this struct from IETF,

```
struct ip6_hdr {

   union {

      struct ip6_hdrctl {
         uint32_t ip6_un1_flow; /* 4 bits version, 8 bits TC, 20 bits
                                      flow-ID */
         uint16_t ip6_un1_plen; /* payload length */
         uint8_t ip6_un1_nxt; /* next header */
         uint8_t ip6_un1_hlim; /* hop limit */
      } ip6_un1;

      uint8_t ip6_un2_vfc; /* 4 bits version, top 4 bits
                                      tclass */
   } ip6_ctlun;
   struct in6_addr ip6_src; /* source address */
   struct in6_addr ip6_dst; /* destination address */
};
```

But I did not know how to fill in the information, for example, how to send a TCP/SYN from  2001:220:806:22:aacc:ff:fe00:1 port 1024 to  2001:220:806:21::4 port 1025?

Could anybody help me or is there any references?

P.S. this is what I have done so far, however there are mismatch between the code  and the real packet captured by Wireshark (as discussed in comments below). I'm not sure it is possible to post a long code in comment section, so I just edit my question.

```
#define PCKT_LEN 2000

int main(void) {
   unsigned char buffer[PCKT_LEN];
   int s;
   struct sockaddr_in6 din;
   struct ipv6_header *ip = (struct ipv6_header *) buffer;
   struct tcpheader *tcp = (struct tcpheader *) (buffer + sizeof (struct ipv6_header));

   memset(buffer, 0, PCKT_LEN);
   din.sin6_family = AF_INET6;
   din.sin6_port = htons(0);
   inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &(din.sin6_addr)); // For routing 

   ip->version = 6;
   ip->traffic_class = 0;
   ip->flow_label = 0;
   ip->length = 40;
   ip->next_header = 6;
   ip->hop_limit = 64;
   inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &(ip->dst)); // IPv6 
   inet_pton(AF_INET6, "::1", &(ip->src)); // IPv6

   tcp->tcph_srcport = htons(atoi("11111"));
   tcp->tcph_destport = htons(atoi("13"));
   tcp->tcph_seqnum = htons(0);
   tcp->tcph_acknum = 0;
   tcp->tcph_offset = 5;
   tcp->tcph_syn = 1;
   tcp->tcph_ack = 0;
   tcp->tcph_win = htons(32752);
   tcp->tcph_chksum = 0; // Done by kernel
   tcp->tcph_urgptr = 0;
   
   s = socket(PF_INET6, SOCK_RAW, IPPROTO_RAW);
   if (s < 0) {
      perror("socket()");
      return 1;
   }
   unsigned short int packet_len = sizeof (struct ipv6_header) + sizeof (struct tcpheader);
   if (sendto(s, buffer, packet_len, 0, (struct sockaddr*) &din, sizeof (din)) == -1) {
      perror("sendto()");
      close(s);
      return 1;
   }
   close(s);
   return 0;
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Maybe [this](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/IPv6_packet) article can help you getting started?

**Edit:**
Using the wikipedia article linked above I made this structure (without knowing what some of the fields means):

```
struct ipv6_header
{
    unsigned int
        version : 4,
        traffic_class : 8,
        flow_label : 20;
    uint16_t length;
    uint8_t  next_header;
    uint8_t  hop_limit;
    struct in6_addr src;
    struct in6_addr dst;
};
```

It's no different than how the header-struct was made for IPv4 in your example. Just create a `struct` containing the fields, in the right order and in the right size, and fill it with the right values.

Just do the same for the TCP headers.

Comment: yeah I know what IPv6 is but how to implement is in C language is quite difficult to me because I am not familiar with. For example, the struct for IPv4 is quite simple and I can easily understand and fill in the information. But for IPv6 it is quite different.

Comment: @nhong: Updated answer a little.

Comment: thank you for your answer, this is somehow different than the struct I got from IETF, but anyway, I will give it a try, please bear with me :)

Comment: I have tried like you said but there is some mismatch between the constructed packet and the real one I capture in Wireshark. the version, traffic class, flow label bits which supposed to be 0110 0000 0000 00..00 but it shows 0000 0110 00..00 instead (seems like two first 4-bit group swap each other). So that Wireshare said the version is 0. Next header, hop limit is correct however payload length is 10240 instead of 40 as expected. Is there any thing related to byte order? I saw that my tcp packet also has mismatch information too.

Comment: @nhong Yes, byte order is important! The `ntohs` and `htons` functions are important to use for all 16-bit values. I don't know if the version/traffic_class/flow_label fields are considered a full 32-bit number, in which case `ntohl` and `htonl` are the functions to use.

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the ipv6 RFCs don't provide the same raw socket interface that you get with ipv4. From what i've seen to create ipv6 packets you have to go a level deeper and use an AF_PACKET socket to send an ethernet frame including your ipv6 packet.